# Pass a module to a called function in python

Tags: python, module, namespaces

I have the following problem:

Suppose I have a file `function.py` that contains:

```
def get_mean(nums):
    return np.mean([nums])
```

and the file `launcher.py` that contains:

```
from function import get_mean

mean = get_mean([1, 2, 3])
print(mean)
```

Now, if you launch `python launcher.py` it will throw `NameError: name 'np' is not defined`.

My question is: is there a way to make the function `get_mean` work by calling it from `launcher.py`, without editing the file `function.py`?

Backstory: a third-party library has a function here represented by `function.py` with an erroneous import, and I have to use that function in my code represented by `launcher.py`, and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do so with a weird hack

```py
import numpy as np
import function
function.__dict__["np"] = np
function.get_mean([1, 2, 3])
```

You are defining the module that is not defined, by adding it in the `__dict__` of the `functions` module.

This is not a very clean way to do things, but is the only available method from my side

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible without editing `function()` because the file already has errors (np not defined).

But, you could try this for function.py:

```
def get_mean(nums):
    import numpy as np
    return np.mean([nums])
```

You could also send np from launcher to function like so:

```
#function.py
def get_mean(nums, np):
    return np.mean([nums])
```

```
#launcher.py
import numpy as np
from function import get_mean
mean = get_mean([1, 2, 3],np)
print(mean)
```

Both of these have this output:

```
2.0
```